# Ascending df gets shown descending when plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following dataset:

| Nr | Aufgabe | Status | Soll | Ist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.01 | Zeitplan erstellen | Projektstart | 2.0 | 1.5 |
| 2.02 | Meilensteine definieren | Projektstart | 1.0 | 0.5 |
| 2.03 | Kurzfassung schreiben | Projektstart | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| 2.04 | Aufgabenstellung erfassen | Projektstart | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| 2.05 | Standards erfassen | Projektstart | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| 2.06 | Schutzbedarfsanalyse erfassen | Projektstart | 1.0 | 0.5 |
| 2.07 | Organisation der IPA Ergebnisse erfassen | Projektstart | 1.0 | 1.5 |
| 2.08 | Projektvorgehen erfassen | Projektstart | 1.0 | 1.5 |
| 2.09 | Projektorganisation erfassen | Projektstart | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| 2.10 | Technische Risikoanalyse erstellen | Projektstart | 1.0 | 1.5 |

With the following lines I create the plot:

```
projektStart = df.loc[df.Status == 'Projektstart']

projektStart.sort_values('Nr',ascending=True)

plt.plot(projektStart.Soll, projektStart.Aufgabe,'go-',alpha=0.5,label='Soll')
plt.plot(projektStart.Ist,projektStart.Aufgabe,'rx-',alpha=0.5,label='Ist')
plt.xlabel('Anzahl Stunden')
plt.ylabel('Aufgabenblöcke')
plt.title('Phase Projektstart')
plt.legend()
```

This produces the following plot in descending order:

[image]

How can I fix the plot to show the entries in ascending order (Zeitplan erstellen 2.01 being shown first and so on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
projektStart.sort_values('Nr',ascending=True)
```

creates a new sorted dataframe, leaving the original dataframe unchanged. To change it you can use

```
projektStart.sort_values('Nr',ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: weirdly enough, I also had to change ascending=True to ascending=false for it to work.